# nginx - direct 5% of traffic to web server, simply return 200 for the rest

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Oh Nginx gods, I beseech thee.

Trying to figure out if I can use weights in nginx to "throttle" the traffic for a particular web server. I want nginx to pass 5% of traffic to a web server (proxy_pass) and the rest just return status code 200. So, it's not really throttling, because I'm not trying to return 429 or anything, just want nginx to "throw out", in a sense, 95% of the traffic for a certain location. The client doesn't care, as long as it gets 200 back.

I know how to define weights between multiple upstream servers, but this isn't quite the same thing. Is it possible? Plugin required?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to break the internet. Can you give more info on why you want this behavior?

Comment: :) It's an endpoint that does statistical sampling. It gets called many times / second, and it's enough if I count just every Nth hit. So N is likely 20, or maybe even 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just do something along the lines of creating another server block in your nginx configuration which handles sending the blind 200.

```
upstream yourupstream {
    server localhost:82 weight=95;
    server yourbackend.com:80 weight=5;
}

server {
    listen 81;

    location / {
        return 200;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location /whatever {
        proxy_pass http://yourupstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. seems simpler. But would this work for a specific location, not the entire server?

Comment: @AssafLavie Yeah there's no reason you can't use whatever location blocks you want (possibly with appropriate rewrites)

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use the [split_clients](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html) module. It is a native Nginx module, that is it's available on most distributions of Nginx. Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
# Use this (and comment out the block below) if you want to
# send ~5% of the users to the upstream server, providing that the users
# have different IP addresses
split_clients "${remote_addr}" $not_a_winner {
    5%      ""; # winners
    *       "no_not_a_winner";
}

# Use this (and comment out the block above) if you want to
# send ~5% of all requests to the upstream server, and it doesn't
# matter if these requests come from the same or different users
split_clients "${connection}${connection_requests}${date_local}" $not_a_winner {
    5%      ""; # winners
    *       "no_not_a_winner";
}

server {
    ...

    location ... {
        # Setting the default_type makes it easier to test 
        # the configuration in a browser.
        default_type text/html; # You can omit this line

        if ($not_a_winner) {
            return 200;
        }

        ...
        proxy_pass ...
        ...
    }
}
```